# Положил жесткий диск

Tags: windows-10, железо, установка, disk

Переустанавливал уже в который раз винду на пк. Обычная родная, чистая переустановка винды 10ки, без внешнего установщика.
На 46% загрузки необходимых для переустановки данных виснет и далее не идет. Выключить было нальзя. Решил перезапустить пк. Но не сработало. Пк выводит что нет boot диска.
Решил воспользоваться внешними носелями установщика, но при выборе места для виндовс сообщает что носителя нет. А свободно только 7мб.
На физическом уровне с диском всё хорошо, без потрескиваний и каких-либо отклонений от нормы.

Comment: Боюсь, вы ошиблись форумом

Comment: Ну затри всё через `gparted livecd` и установи заново. В чём проблема?